# How does Strava treat power data while resting?

Tags: power, strava

I'm trying to understand how strava treats power data when there's no power

I think power is included when you are riding downhill (0 power, non-zero speed).

- What about the idle time while you sleep or eat (0 power, 0 speed).
- What about walking the bike (0 power, non-zero speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick calculation it looks to me like Strava calculates average power the same way as average speed. It’s using total distance/power divided by *moving* time (not total time and not pedaling or working time or anything like that). This means the average power displayed by Strava will drop during descents but not while standing at a traffic light.

According to this page it will use total time instead of moving time if you select the “Race” type for a ride:
https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001188684-Moving-Time-Speed-and-Pace-Calculations

Comment: How can you do a "quick calculation"?

Comment: I looked at one of my workouts and calculated average power once with total power divided by total time and once with total power divided by moving time (and also did the same for speed, just to check).

Comment: In my opinion Strava should improve their labeling and call it “Average moving speed” and “Average power while moving” or something like that. Normally I’d assume that an average uses total (elapsed) time.

Comment: I double checked this, by taking out "walking the bike portion " of my ride, and strava shows different ap/np after taking that part. 

So your reasoning applys to np as well.

Comment: where can I get total power from strava? Total work?

Comment: Total work, yes. Work is power times duration.